# How do I solve for the Nash equilibria in the Hotelling price competition model

Tags: game-theory

I'm trying to find the Nash equilibria in the following problem:

> Two firms produce an identical product with no fixed costs. The
> marginal cost of each firm $i=1,2$ is $c_i\in (0,1)$. Customers are
> distributed uniformly on $[1,2]$. The location of firm $i$ is $i$. The
> firms simultaneously choose prices. We denote by $p_i\in [0,\bar{p}]$
> the price chosen by firm $i$, where $\bar{p}>0$ is some large number.
> Customers have linear transportation costs: if customer $x\in [1,2]$
> buys from firm 1 then he incurs a cost of $x-1$, and if he buys from
> firm 2 then he incurs a cost of $2-x$. The value of a unit of the
> product is $V>0$ for each customer, and each customer buys one unit of
> the product, from the firm that maximizes his utility. This is a game
> in normal form with two players (the firms).

**How do I find the best response functions** for both firms? Right now I have solved that: The net value of buying from firm 1 is $V_1=V-(x-1)-p_1$, and the net value of buying from firm 2 is $V_2=V-(2-x)-p_2$. For consumers located at $x=1, V_1=V-p_1, V_2=V-(1+p_2)$. If $p_1>1+p_2$, then even for consumers living at $x=1$, it's too expensive to buy from firm 1. Thus, all consumers buy from firm 2. For consumers located at $x=2, V_1=V-(1+p_1), V_2=V-p_2$. If $p_2>1+p_1$, then even for consumers living at $x=2$, it's too expensive to buy from firm 2. Thus, all consumers buy from firm 1.

Then if $p_2-1<p_1<1+p_2\implies p_2-p_1\in [-1,1]$, then when $V_1=V_2$, we have $x^*=\frac{3+p_2-p_1}{2}$. Then for all consumers located on the right of $x^*$, they buy from firm 2; for all consuemrs located on the left of $x^*$, they buy from firm 1.

How do I proceed from this?

**edit**: ok... so from what I've gathered, the payoff function should be
\begin{align}
u_i(p_i,p_{-i})=\begin{cases} 0\;\text{if }p_i\geq p_{-i}+1\\ (p_i-c_i)\cdot 1 \;\text{if }p_i\leq p_{-i}-1\\ (p_i-c_i)(\frac{1+p_{-i}-p_i}{2})\;\text{if }p_i\in (p_{-i}-1,p_{-i}+1)\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then the best response function should be
\begin{align}
BR_i(p_{-i})=\begin{cases} \frac{1+p_{-i}+c_i}{2}\;\text{(you can compute this by FOC of the 3rd case from $u$)} \;\text{if $p_{-i}$ is in a range}\\ p_{-i}-1\;\text{if $p_{-i}$ is in a range}\end{cases}
\end{align}
but I'm having trouble finding the range of $p_{-i}$.